# How to use ls function in Unix while the script and the files are not in the same directory

Tags: for-loop, ubuntu, unix, ls

I have a folder that contains several subfolders, such as PROGRAMME, containing the scripts and URLS, containing the pure text files and TABLEAUX is the subfolders for output.

[image: You can see the detail in the image 1.]

Now I need to *ls* the subfolder URL and write to the subfolder TABLEAUX. However, when I use the function ls in for loop, it's said:

> ls: cannot access 'URLS': No such file or directory

I guess it's because that the script and the subfolder are not in the same place and I've changed the directory to where the script is (if not, I can't execute the script.) like it shows in the image 2.[image: image2]

And my codes are here:

```
#command: bash <name of script.sh> <folder_input> <folder_output>

dossier_url=$1
dossier_tableaux=$2
echo $dossier_url
echo $dossier_tableaux       # it's ok until here
for fichier in $(ls $dossier_url); do
echo $fichier;
done                # Ubuntu shows "ls: cannot access 'URLS': No such file or directory"
```

Comment: Note that Ubuntu is not Unix. Also Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sauvé !

I shouldn't change directory to PROGRAMMES but should use the command:

```
bash PROGRAMMES/<name of scipt.sh> <input> <output>
```